# When downloading and installing both RUBY and PYTON 3.11 I cannot complete it always throws an error

Tags: python, ruby, terminal

Noob here I am extremely illiterate when it comes to this kind of work but I'm going in deep.

I have been trying to download and run both Ruby and Python as I am doing a paid course right now and for the life of me I cannot complete it and I do not know why. Maybe I've changed something or made a mistake maybe I'm just uneducated.

When i try to download and run RUBY through terminal. i get this:::
ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21] it wont show the new version i have downloaded?

When i try to run Python which on my course these are the steps:

```
vim ~/.zshrc 

Vim is a text editor and allows you to make changes to files directly from the shell. To      make the edits:

1. Press the "I" key on your keyboard.
2.  Add the following line and remember to replace 3.x with the Python version that was installed on your system: 

shell PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.x/libexec/bin:${PATH}" 

3. Press the esc key to exit from insert mode. 

4. Hold down the shift key and press the colon key represented by : & ; 

5. Type wq! and then hit Enter to exit vim.
```

6. Run the following:

I GET (I deleted what i think sensitive info is):

```
Last login: Fri Jul 14 16:12:38 on ttys00
/Users/-----/.zshrc:1: command not found: shell
@-MacBook-Pro ~ % ruby -v
ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]
-MacBook-Pro ~ % vim ~/.zshrc 
-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Please help and let me know if any of this is of any help.

Its all explained above.

Comment: Note: if this is for a paid course, in addition to asking random people on the Interwebs, you can also ask the people who you are paying to explain this to you. After all, you are paying them to teach you this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

To enter python interpreter from terminal type python3

To exit the python interpreter press ctrl+c or ctrl+d
If you want to run python file (the one with .py extension) go to file path with cd command and write in the terminal:

```
python3 file_name.py
```

Or you can run the file from any path in the terminal by specifying the full path of the file like this:

```
python3 ~/Desktop/folder1/folder2/test.py
```

Ruby works the same.
I don't recommend vim but if you want to use it use the following commands.
To create or edit file use this command in the terminal:

```
vim file_name.rb
```

Press the "I" key on your keyboard to enter "insert mode".
Write your code, for example:

```
puts "hello world"
```

To exit and save the changes hit the Escape key, then type :wq and hit Enter.
To run the file write the following command in terminal and hit enter:

```
ruby file_name.rb
```